# JavaScript: Change src files on environment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deployment, web-deployment

I have a web application, with a simple `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="assets/js/scripts.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to change the `src` of my static files because in production they're going to be in a place different then in development. But one requirement: I can't change it through build.

So I'm thinking about having a local file like `application.properties` with the source for dev mode and deploy the same file in production with different sources.

Is there a way to do it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in head which environment it is and then insert the script in head or body depending on current environment(dev or prod).

```html
<head>
  <script>
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var devmode = /*condition to check if current enviroment is Development or Production*/ true;
    if (devmode === true) {
      // Development Scripr
      script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.8.0/lodash.js";
    } else {
      // Production Script
      script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.8.0/lodash..min.js";
    }
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  </script>
</head>
```

**NOTE:** Above solution works in the most of the modern browsers. but, its recommended to use good AMD solutions like [Require.JS](http://requirejs.org/), [yepnopejs](http://yepnopejs.com/) (which is now merged with modernizr) or [$script.js](http://www.dustindiaz.com/scriptjs) etc. its because they takes care of some of edge cases for the cross browser quirks.

Comment: @MatheusLima.  Require.JS, yepnopejs etc. all these AMD loaders also internally do the same thing but they put listeners to detect loading of scripts. if you just want to add scripts to the DOM then the above approach is good enough. but if you want to detect whether js file is loaded and after its loaded initialise something, then you should go with  AMD library.